# get first file from directory do instructions and do the same for the next one c#

Tags: c#, loops, directory

I want to do some instructions on some files located in folder. So now all i can do now is to do this to the first file , and i want to add the possibility to do the same instructions for the next file after finished .

Here is the code I'm using to get the first file

```
   var imgPath = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Folder_fact"), "*.pdf").First();
  //instructions here 
  // i want to add here the function to move to the next file
```

Comment: Have you heard about `foreach`?

Comment: Yes and i've already used it but it's not working , that's why I proceed by getting the first and looking for getting the next one

Comment: @ItShine could you explain what was not working with foreach? There are many ways to loop over a collection of data but foreach is definitively one of them.

Comment: i can't get the next file

Answer (score 2):

[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) return all files with the specified pattern, but with your `First` call then you get only the first one. Remove that `First` and then loop over the results

However, as from MSDN, it is better to use [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid loading all the info before starting the enumeration.

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Folder_fact"), "*.pdf"))
{
     // here the variable file is the full pathname to your PDF file....
}
```

Comment: as a side note: if you want to stop before to process all the file you can use the `break` inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Folder_fact"));

var files= from f in DirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
           where f.Extension == ".pdf"
           select f.FullName;

foreach(var file in files)
{
     // do something
}
```